# Apache give access permission only to server

Tags: php, apache, file-permissions, wampserver

I've got WAMP server on my Windows machine (just starting to study Servers and what not so I'm new to all this).

What I want to know is how can I give Apache permission to access a folder, but users should not be able to access that folder.

I've got a folder containing images which anyone would be able to view if they knew the structure of my server's file system and directories. Therefore, what I wish to do is that this folder should be accessible by my .html and .php pages but not by a user who inputs the URL of the folder/image directly in their browser.

I realize this may not be possible, but there must be some alternative to what I'm trying to achieve. I'm very new to all this so I'd like to know if I'm going about this wrong way, whether I'm on the right track or if I simply need to edit my permissions in the httpd.conf file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not possible. The way the browser loads images when they're referenced in your website is not different from the way it does load them when a user enters the same URL directly. SO you get either both or none.

What you CAN do is: disable indexing, so entering just the directory name without the image name results in an "Access Forbidden" error. For that, put this anywhere in your Apache config:

```
<Directory c:/path/to/your/directory>
    Options -Indexes
</Directory>
```

(You may have to use Backslashes on Windows, not sure. Haven't done any Apache config on Windows fore some time. Can anybody help me out here?)

Another thing you can do is to write an PHP (or use any other server side language) script that reads those images and pases them to the browser. That way, you could check the referrer the browser sends and react to it. But I would not recommend this, as it yields more trouble than it solves, therefore I won't give you a ready made script for this.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, your solution is what I wanted.